# how can I create this

Tags: delimiters

I'm not able to create this in Latex.. I tried with array but the parenthesis goes in the line below.. can someone help me please

[image]

Comment: This is surely a duplicate

Comment: `cases` environment, for example

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\text{La disabilità e le sue caractteristiche}\begin{cases}
\text{motorie}\\
\text{sensoriali}\\
\text{cognitive}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do with this, excuse me

```
$ \left \{ \begin{array}{l } \mbox{disabilità}\\
\mbox{cognitiva}  \end{array} \right. $
```

Comment: My search-foo today is weak; this has been treated elsewhere, it's just a question of finding the right search key. In the meantime, use `tabular` and not `array`, so you don't need `\mbox`.

Comment: @egreg: "Luke, use the foo".  May the foo be with you.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes In a place where LaTeX is discussed, “foo” is certainly more apt than “fu”. ;-)